# Javascript Calculations Not Returning Correct Amount?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that calculates price, quantity, and shipping. When The numbers are added together it should display like this:

> Sub-Total: [amount]
>
> Shipping: [amount]
>
> Total : [sub-total + shipping]

What happens is the total is correct but the shipping shows the total amount, not the shipping amount.

Here is the script I am using to calculate the totals:

```
function calculate() {
var total = 0;
var shiptotal = 0;
var subtotal = 0;
$('.button-click').each(function () {
    var amt = parseInt($(this).prev().val());
    var qty = parseInt($(this).parent().find(".quantity").val());
    var ship = parseInt($(this).parent().find(".ik-ship").val());
    total += ((ship += amt) * qty);
    shiptotal += (ship * qty);
    subtotal += (amt * qty);
    
});
$('#Amount').val(total.toFixed(2));
$('.total-amount').html( total.toFixed(2) );
$('.sub-total-amount').html( subtotal.toFixed(2) );
$('.shipping-amount').html( shiptotal.toFixed(2) );
}
```

HTML:

```
<li>
 <label for="CAT_Custom_410680" class="bold">Spin Pen - $62.00  <br> <a class="fancybox" href="#spin-pen">Learn More</a></label>
     <input type="text" class="cat_textbox quantity " id="CAT_Custom_410680" name="CAT_Custom_410680" maxlength="4000" value="0" />
     <input type="hidden" class="ik-ship" value="1.00">
     <input type="hidden" class="ik-price" value="62.00">
     <ul class="button-group radius button-click">
        <li><a href="#" class="small button secondary"><i class="fa fa-plus"><span class="hide">+</span></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="small button secondary"><i class="fa fa-minus"><span class="hide">-</span></i></a></li>
     </ul>
</li>
```

As you will notice the shipping cost is a preset cost.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

[Here is a Fiddle of the Code](http://jsfiddle.net/XXzUG/1/)

Comment: Why are you calculating the total first? Why not just add the shipping & subtotal together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks wrong:

```
total += ((ship += amt) * qty);
```

Do you mean:

```
total += ((ship + amt) * qty);
```

`+` instead of `+=` in the inner expression.

Comment: That was it! Such a simple mistake. Thank you for the help.